# Remove files from master at github

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

First time playing with git, and I accidentally added all hidden files with my commit. Now that I have set up my .gitignore, and committed my changes, all the files ending with "~" are still there.

How do I commit my local files, and remove those from master that are not supposed to be there any more?

Comment: You mean like besides the normal way of doing git rm and committing it? You want to rewrite history like the commit never happened?

Comment: You can do that; just reset your head to before the commit and push that to the repository, making that the head. The repo has to be configured allow non-fast-forward pushes though. Also, anyone pulling from that repo will have to do a hard reset to follow that change. The commit becomes garbage since it is unreferenced; it gets garbage collected (in 45 days or something like that?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `git rm --cached FILENAME` to delete it from the repository but keep the file physically and `git add FILENAME` to add a file to your repository. You will need to commit both of these changes with `git commit`

Comment: I didn't know about the ``--cached`` flag. +1 for that. :)

Comment: Is there any way to remove all untracked/ignored files, so I don't have to manually do this? Gedit creates a hidden file for everything it has opened apparently.

Comment: Are the files spread all over your directory structure? If not, use some GUI utilities like tortoisegit to easily do that.

Comment: windows search to list all your "~" files + tortoisegit = win

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a DOS batch file that can help:

SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b *.dll') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b *.pdb') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b *.txt') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b *.cache') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b *.force') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
GOTO :eof

 :subroutine
  git rm --cached %1
  set /a count+=1
  GOTO :eof
```